# Equivalence of left and right regular action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

This is Exercise 36 of section 4.3 (p. 132) from *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit & Foote.

> Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym} \pi_1:G\rightarrow \Sym(G)$ be the **left** regular representation
> afforded by the action of $G$ on itself by **left** multiplication
> defined by $\pi_1(g)=\sigma_g$ so that $\sigma_g(x)=gx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> Let $\pi_2:G\rightarrow \Sym(G)$ be the **right** regular
> representation afforded by the action of $G$ on itself by **right**
> multiplication defined by $\pi_2(h)=\tau_h$ so that
> $\tau_h(x)=xh^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> Prove that $\sigma_g=\tau_h$ iff $g,h\in Z(G)$. Deduce that
> $\pi_1(G)\cap\pi_2(G)=\pi_1(Z(G))=\pi_2(Z(G))$

The 'only if ' part is as follows: Suppose $\sigma_g=\tau_h$. For all $x\in G$, $\sigma_g(x)=gx=xh^{-1}=\tau_h(x)$. In particular, $gh=hh^{-1}=1$, so $h=g^{-1}$. So $\sigma_g(x)=gx=xg=x(g^{-1})^{-1}=\tau_{g^{-1}}(x)$ for all $x\in G$. So $g\in Z(G)$. Also $h=g^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

As you can see, the 'only if' part is quite easy. What's frustrating me is the 'if' part. **Whenever $g$ and $h$ lie in the center of $G$, why is $\sigma_g=\tau_h$?** This is so counter-intuitive: Since $1\in Z(G)$, by letting $g\in Z(G)$, $g\neq 1$, we get $gx=x$ for all $x\in G$, and so $g=1$! And so $G$ is centerless!

Comment: The "if part" is false. If g and g are central, then left multiplication by g is the same as right multiplication by the inverse of g, and the latter is the same as right multiplication by the inverse of h iff g ans $h^{-1}$ are equal

Comment: So you mean there is a typo in the book? It's not uncommon though. I've seen 'if and only if' being typed as 'if and only'.

Comment: there is no typo in the book , in atleast my D&F copy. :"iff g,h $\in Z(G)$ and $g=h^{-1}$".This is the question

Comment: @Riju There's no such '$g=h^{-1}$' in my copy.

Comment: As you've already seen (indicated in your last paragraph), the disproof of "$\sigma_g=\tau_h$ if $g,h\in Z(G)$" is quite easy, so indeed it is a typo. Thus everything appears cleared up now.